Bad habit tracking database schema
I'm building an application to track negative habits. I came up with the following database schema
+-------+---------------+-----------+
| Users | Habits        | HabitType |
+-------+---------------+-----------+
| id    | id            | id        |
| email | user_id       | name      |
|       | habit_type_id |           |
|       | date          |           |
+-------+---------------+-----------+

Since we're dealing with negative habits, having an entry means a "negative" event occured. For example when the user smoked a cigarette, there will be a record with the date of that event.
Now I'm wondering if this is the best way to go about this. I'm mostly wondering:
Calculating the current streak and longest streak means we will have to loop over all records, adding records for days that are not filled, and seeing where gaps exist. Looping over a large data set doesn't seem like a good way to go about this?
Is there a better way to structure this database?

I think the structure is good, your making it so you can add as many users, habits, and user/habit combinations.  Not super clear on what you want to do after you get the data in there with streaks, but there are ways to do queries with sums/order by/ranking that should be able to give you what you want without looping through every single row for each user.  We would need data examples and desired output to be able to help more on that.

The table design seems great so far but, if you want to calculate streaks efficiently, I think it would help if you would do it as the user posts new data to the database.
I would suggest this change
+-------+---------------+-----------+
| Users | Habits        | HabitType |
+-------+---------------+-----------+
| id    | id            | id        |
| email | user_id       | name      |
|       | habit_type_id |           |
|       | date          |           |
|       | streak        |           |
+-------+---------------+-----------+

Taking your example with smoking into consideration, when there is an insert in the database with the habit, check if the habit has been inserted the day before and increment a streak count for that entry. This way it will be easier to get the longest streak.
You would still need another table to cache these things if you want to use it long term but that depends on your use case.
